# UITextView is not scrolled well

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView that works well, till it's content is larger than it's own frame.
In that case it's scrolled down, but for some reason I cant re-scroll it back to the beginning, but only a few lines up.
How do I control the size of the content and the range of scrolling?
thanks

Comment: Can you post your UITextView declaration code? Or at least some info about it - this is not normal.

Comment: it's just in the xib... I can't even think of code lines that can actually be connected somehow...   i'll try to think of some code to show, though I really don't know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid problem, but I'll answer anyway:

I had a scrollViewDidScroll method in order to control a UITableView scrolling.
This method was called also when my textView was scrolled - and actually made some troubles.
so I just checked the sender in the first line:

```
if (sender==textView) return;
```

thanks for the help..